# Why does Scala sometimes ignore types that are clearly defined?

Tags: scala, generics, types

so here's the problem I keep running into various situations with Scala - it seemingly ignores the implied type, even when the situation is clear. Granted this could be my understanding I admit, but when it comes to underscore placeholders I keep running into trouble. For example below (this is fictional just to prove the point).The 2nd position of trait X has to be <:X[*,*] of some kind. There's no ambiguity here - so anywhere that scala sees this position, regardless of how weak it's coded - the contact is X and I should have access to functions like "doesX". Isn't that indisputable? No matter how poorly I deal with that position in the code, I must at least get X. Why does Scala constantly ignore this fact when you get deep into the type system? Any pointers would be appreciated, thank you!

```
object TestRun extends App {

  trait X[T, Y<:X[_,_]] {
    def doesX:Unit
    def providesY:Y
  }

  class Test extends X[Int,Test]{
    override def doesX: Unit = println("etc..")
    def providesY:Test =  new Test
  }

  val a:X[_,_] = new Test //yes I know I could define a better here, its just to demo. I shouldn't have to explicitly relabel the 2nd _ as _<:X[_,<:X[ etc..
  val b = a.providesY //clearly this has to be at least a (something) WITH X, but scala claims this as "Any"

  b.doesX //error won't compile!!

  //trait

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you write:

```
val a: X[_, _] = new Test
            ^
      //  This is treated as if the type parameter is Any, for the most part
```

You are telling the compiler that `a` is an `X`, where you *don't care* what its type parameters are. That is, the unbounded wildcard `_` is assumed to have an upper-bound of `Any`, and that's it.

`providesY` uses the second type parameter of `X` to determine its return type, but for `a` the compiler was told that to discard it. So `b` is just an `Any`. This is easier to see using the REPL:

```
scala> val a: X[_, _] = new Test
a: X[_, _] = Test@27abe2cd

scala> val b = a.providesY
b: Any = Test@f5f2bb7
```

Therefore, `b.doesX` fails to compile because the compiler now thinks it is `Any`. The simple solution is not to use wild cards for types (or any existential types in general, most of the time you do not want this).

```
scala> val a: X[Int, Test] = new Test
a: X[Int,Test] = Test@1134affc   

scala> val b = a.providesY
b: Test = Test@6fc6f14e

scala> b.doesX
etc..
```

Or you could simply leave off the type annotation, and let the compiler infer the correct type.